# bash process data from two files

Tags: bash

file1:

```
456
445
2323
```

file2:

```
433
456
323
```

I want get the deficit of the data in the two files and output to output.txt, that is:

```
23
-11
2000
```

How do I realize this? thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk '{ print $1 - $2 }'
23
-11
2000
```

Comment: @user1224398 FYI, neither awk or paste are bash commands -- they're generic UNIX commands, available with any shell or no shell at all; the only thing the shell is doing here is connecting them together with a pipe. To tell whether something is part of bash, you can run `type something`; if it comes back with `something is a shell keyword` or `something is a shell builtin`, that will tell you that it's part of the shell proper.

Answer (score 1):

In pure bash, with no external tools:

```
while read -u 4 line1 && read -u 5 line2; do
  printf '%s\n' "$(( line1 - line2 ))"
done 4<file1 5<file2
```

This works by opening both files (attaching them to file descriptors 4 and 5); going into a loop in which we read one line from each descriptor per iteration (exiting the loop if *either* has no value), and calculate and print the result.

Answer (score 1):

Use paste to create the formulae, and use bc to perform the calculations:

```
paste -d - file1 file2 | bc
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use paste and awk to operate between columns:

```
paste -d" " file1 file2 | awk -F" " '{print ($1-$2)}'
```

Or even pipe to a file:

```
paste -d" " file1 file2 | awk -F" " '{print ($1-$2)}' > output.txt
```

Hope it helps!